# Web middleware group not applied to error pages in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-middleware

I am upgrading a Laravel 4.2 application to Laravel 5.4.

The errors pages (in resources/views/errors) extend a common layout.blade.php which makes use of variables shared via View::share() in middleware, middleware which I have included in the web middleware group.

The error message is 'Undefined variable: ...' from the blade as the web middleware group isn't being used for the error pages.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you add some relevant code? :)

Comment: @Andy Holmes; There is not much code to look at; `View::share('var', 123)` in the middleware handle method then using the variable in the layout blade as `$var`. The middleware is in the 'web' middleware group.

Comment: In that case add your middleware to your `app/Http/Kernel.php` especially in the `protected $middleware =` array as well

Comment: @Maraboc; I added `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class` to the `$middleware` group and it changed the error to `Session store not set on request` so I added `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` to $middleware also, and now we are back to the original error of `Undefined variable`.

Comment: in the first look i presume that you want share the errors variable but after you added you first comment i updated mine, so did you create a middleware or witch middleware did you use to share your var? in each case that middleware that you should add it t `protected $middleware =`

Comment: I split out the middleware into two so I have one with just the View::share()s and moved this one into global `$middleware`. It makes the application work but the problem is that this will run on api routes etc where it is going to affect performance?

Answer (score 0):

If the route isn't setup to run web middleware then it won't be run by the time it hits the error view. For example, this could happen if it's a 404 that doesn't have an existing route and no catch-all to fall back to.

If this is the case then the middleware in question will need to be in the `protected $middleware` property in Kernel.php rather than the 'web' middleware group.